# StringBuilder appends newline "\n" char

Tags: xml, newline, stringbuilder

I am using StringBuilder in an xml parser DefaultHandler2.
builder is a StringBuilder.

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    builder.append(ch, start, length);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName){
    strVar = builder.toString();    
}
```

The problem is now that `StringBuilder` appends "\n" new line char?
It can also be that `builder.setLength(0)` is adding the newline.

If I ware to accept this new line, it is not possible to remove the new line char from the string. `strVar.removeAll("\\n","")` in all possible variations is not working.

Any idear?

Thanks
Regards
Christian

Answer (score 2):

StringBuilder isn't appending any '\n' chars (unless you tell it to).

The '\n' character is originating elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the newline character is part of the `ch` array. `StringBuilder` only appends things that you tell it to, and won't append a newline of its own accord.

As to `strVar.removeAll("\n", "")` not removing the newline, don't forget to use the result of the call:

```
strVar = strVar.removeAll("\n", "")
```

Strings in Java are immutable, so simply calling `removeAll()` won't modify the original string object.

Comment: Thank you for the immutable string - I tipped it useful. I am looking deeper into "characters"..